# osx trackpad gesture to switch between chrome tabs

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser, magic-trackpad, gesture

Is there a trackpad gesture to switch between Chrome browser tabs? I understand there may be one for Safari.

Comment: This is not natively supported in OS X when using Chrome. As suggested below, use Better Touch Tool instead or the keyboard shortcuts (ctrl + tab or ⌘ + ⌥ + arrows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Better Touch Tool](http://bettertouchtool.net) to assign custom gestures to any application. Here's an example how You this would look like in BTT (tip tap gestures to switch tabs):

[image: tip taps to switch Tabs]

Comment: Managed to get it work with BigSur after giving Accessibility permission + disabling `System Preferences > Trackpad > More gestures > Swipe between pages`. Although gesture detection is not as good as system built-in one. Too bad the browsers don't offer a built in customization way.

Comment: BTW: since I'm new to MacOS I didn't know what TipTap was, [this page](https://www.viget.com/articles/trackpad-shortcuts/) illustrates it well

Comment: @jakub.g yea tip tap is specific to BTT, it's not macOS standard gesture.